# Return Firebase Database Array To Another Function But Returns Empty

Tags: database, firebase, swiftui, completionhandler

I'm making a Cue Card App. I added my database to an array but upon calling that array in another function (where I want to make changes to the array), it returns empty. I've done lots of searching on this topic and found that I must use a completion handler, which I think I've done. There's lots of information on this topic out there, such as https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/07/swift-closures-and-firebase-handling.html but I can't seem to make it work for my app.
Cue Card View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CueCardView: View {

var viewModel = CueCardViewModel()
@State private var isShowingAnswer = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.white)
        VStack{
              Text("heloo")
                .onAppear{
                    self.viewModel.initializeCues()
                }
        }
        .padding(20)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        self.isShowingAnswer.toggle()
    
    }
    
}


}

struct C1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    
    CueCardView().previewDevice("iPhone 12")
}

}
```

Cue Card Model:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CueCardModel : Identifiable {
var id: String = UUID().uuidString
var term: String
var answer: String
}
```

Download Data :

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

var dbRef = Firestore.firestore()
struct DataDownloader {
func downloadCues(completion: @escaping ([CueCardModel]) -> Void) {
    var array = [CueCardModel]()
    dbRef.collection("Cues").getDocuments(){(snap, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print(err)
        } else {
            guard let snap = snap else {return}
            
                for doc in snap.documents {
                let id = doc.documentID
                let term = doc.get("term") as! String
                let answer = doc.get("answer") as! String
                let cue = CueCardModel(id: id, term: term, answer: answer)
                array.append(cue)
            }
            completion(array)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Cue Card ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class CueCardViewModel: ObservableObject {

let dataDownloader = DataDownloader()

func initializeCues() {
    dataDownloader.downloadCues() { array in
        print(array)
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: You should add print statements throughout the functions and see where it's getting caught. I would start by adding a print at the beginning of downloadCues to make sure it's being called.. another print within the function where you are checking the snap values.. and probably one at the beginning of initializeCues to make sure its being called. Just looking quickly, you may need to add an init() to the CueCardViewModel to actually call initializeCues?

Comment: Great suggestion that I always overlook. It seems to not run the for doc in snap.documents {} loop in the DataDownloader file.

Comment: Is it getting to the "guard let snap = snap else {return}" statement? I'm guessing it's returning there. That would mean the function is not getting a snapshot at dbRef.collection("Cues"). Make sure you are accessing the correct path/collection. I believe it is case sensitive ("Cues" vs "cues").

Comment: And you are a mind reader! My database collection was named "Cue" not "Cues." I had worked on this for about 4 hours now. Thank You!

Comment: Haha I've run into similar problems myself. I've posted an answer with a recommendation for you too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the query path is exactly the same as you have set it up in Firebase. I would recommend creating a Struct for the names of all of your collections (and probably additional Structs for each Field within each collection) to avoid typing out explicit strings when you make queries. It's also common practice to keep all of your database fields lowercase, to avoid case sensitive String issues. For example:

Create a global Struct with collection:

```
struct DatabaseCollections {
    static let cue = "cue"
    static let nextCollection = "collection_two"
}
```

Usage:

```
dbRef.collection(DatabaseCollections.cue).getDocuments...
```